# Gradle sync failed: Version: 5.8.0 is lower than the minimum version (9.0.0) required for google-services plugin

Tags: android, gradle

I am using admin SDK in my app but when I sync my project I am getting error I tried to change admin SDK version but nothing has changed please help me to sync my project correctly, I have found many other solutions for this kind of error in stack overflow but they did not solve my problem

**App.Gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "Myid"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.8.0'
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Project.gradle**

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: why are you not using latest Gradle version 11.8.0? it is latest version

Comment: will it work if i change gradle version? actually i did not update android studio

Comment: you are using Google version 3.1.0 so you have to use the latest version of the firebase.

Comment: Yeah i am using the latest version of firebase can you tell me where should i change my version number on above code and which version should i enter?

Comment: firebase-admin:5.8.0 is the latest version  https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/java

Comment: i did not even compiled my app i just added sdk and while syncing gradle files i got this problem, thanks

Comment: this Gradel is for Java not android, admin version is not for android. I check it on https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use **firebase-admin-sdk** with:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.8.0'
```

in Android. Because it is for your **Server** not for your Android client.

Please read more at [Add the Firebase Admin SDK to Your Server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app)

From the documentation:

> **Prerequisites**
>   Before you begin, make sure you have the following:
>
> 1. If using the Admin Node.js SDK, a server running Node.js 4.0+
> 2. If using the Admin Java SDK, a server running Java 7+
> 3. If using the Admin Python SDK, a server running Python 2.7+ or 3.x
> 4. A server app

Comment: is there any other solution? how can i do this with android client then?

Comment: You need to setup the server for using it then create your custom api to communicate with your server.